# How to save data from csv file to dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to read data in a csv file and save it as dictionary. The first three columns are Keys and the second column is value.

I tried to do it in the following way. But it did not save the data into the computer memory, just a way to read it.

Actually, I need to save all the data into g(i,j,t).

For example, g(1,1,2)=20, g(1,1,3)=40....

How could I do it?

```
df1_head = [ 'i', 'j', 't', 'g']
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/C1/input01g.csv', names=df1_head)
def g(i,j,t):
    return (df1[(df1['i'] == i) & (df1['j'] == j) & (df1['t'] == t)]['g'])
```

Comment: Is that a 3D CSV file?

Comment: How do you calculate **g(1,1,2)=20, g(1,1,3)=40** ?  Some data will be helpful.

Comment: *first three columns are Keys* and *the second column is value*, wait for me to understand that.

Comment: Sorry, it should be the first three columns are Keys and the fourth column is value

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works :

```
import csv

my_dict = {}
with open('abc.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in spamreader:
        print(row)
        key_list = row[0][0:5]
        val = row[0].split(',')[3]
        my_dict.__setitem__(key_list,val)
print(my_dict)
```

**abc.csv**

```
i,j,k,10
p,q,r,20
w,r,t,30
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way:

```
g={}
df1_head = [ 'i', 'j', 't', 'g']
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/C1/input01g.csv', names=df1_head)

for x in range(len(df1['g'])):
    g[(df1['i'][x],df1['j'][x],df1['t'][x])] =df1['g'][x]
```

Answer (score -1):

I am asuming you have only 4 colum total and 4th is key in that and other 3 should be value in your csv file and written logic as below, But if your csv is in different way they may have to modify the below code accordinly

```
dic = {}
with open("my.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        linedata = line.strip().split(',')
        dic[linedata[3]] = linedata[:-1]
print dic
```

Comment: Some one has down voted my answer, please provide proper reason why you have done down vote